# JAXB class for complex relations

Tags: java, jaxb

I would like to define a JAXB mapping class for the following structure.

```
{
"family members": ["me","my dad","someone else"],
"relations" : [{"me":17 years, "my dad":40 years, "relation":son & father}, {"my dad":40 years, "me":17 years, "relation":father & son},{"me": 17 years, "someone else":50 years, "relation":ancestor}]
}
```

How should I annotate the POJO ? Please ignore suggestions on avoiding redundancy, or other alternative ways of storing this information.

Comment: you can define XSD for the expected format and use xmls instead. The one you pasted looks more like json object

Comment: Yes. In fact it is the output for my REST api. ( I am sending Accept- Application/json through my client )

Comment: What library do you use to marshal/unmarshal JSON?

Comment: @Dawid Pytel: If you are interested in this, **RESTful Webservices with Java (Jersey / JAX-RS)** are your best go.